# How to dynamically move inside a nested dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dict with a dynamical number of nested dicts inside of it, something like:

```
my_dict = {"a": {"b": {"c: {...}}}}
```

I need to dynamically move inside this dict, for instance I'd like to do the following:

```
levels = ["a", "b", "c"]
my_dict[levels[0]][levels[1]][levels[2]] = "something"
```

where the number of items inside "levels" may vary.

I can partially achieve the same result for a limited number of items inside "levels" by writing something like this:

```
if len(levels) == 1:
    my_dict[levels[0]] = "something"
elif len(levels) == 2:
    my_dict[levels[0]][levels[1]] = "something"
elif len(levels) == 3:
    my_dict[levels[0]][levels[1]][levels[2]] = "something"
(...)
```

but I'm looking for a more general and elegant solution.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a lot of code here to go on, but for what you have given, you can define

```
def get(d, keys):
    for key in keys:
        d = d[key]
    return d

def set(d, keys, value):
    d = get(d, keys[:-1])
    d[keys[-1]] = value
```

And then use it like this

```
my_dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":{}}}}
set(my_dict, ["a", "b", "c"], "something")
print get(my_dict, ["a", "b", "c"])
```

---

A functional alternative for `get`:

```
def get(d, keys):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d[key], keys, d)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. I've tried a similar solution by myself but I missed the "-1"s of the set function.